# Why is sbt 0.13.9 reporting that it's 0.13.8?

Tags: scala, sbt

I downloaded and installed `sbt-0.13.9.msi` from the [official sbt site](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html). However it reports that it's actually 0.13.8:

```
>sbt --version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
sbt launcher version 0.13.8
```

`sbt about` reports the same thing:

```
>sbt about
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\$USER$\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Set current project to documents (in build file:/C:/Users/$USER$/Documents/)

[info] This is sbt 0.13.8
[info] The current project is {file:/C:/Users/$USER$/Documents/}documents 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is this a bug?

Comment: How you can be certain that the sbt you just installed is the same sbt you are running? Is it possible you have multiple sbts installed in different locations?

Comment: This is a freshly installed machine. I have never installed sbt 0.13.8 on it, nor does `Add/Remove Software` show any other installations of sbt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sbt` is set to `0.13.8` in your project configuration.

Your `build.properties` file probably contains the line `sbt.version=0.13.8`

If you want your project to be executed by version `0.13.9` simply update the value.

Comment: I don't have a `build.properties` file, and if I go into an empty directory that has no projects sbt still reports the same thing.

Comment: Creating a `build.properties` with `sbt.version=0.13.9` solved my problem. sb 0.13.9 defaults to sb 0.13.8 when no `build.properties` file is found apparently.

Comment: If you're sure that's true, you should report it at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues . I'm not able to reproduce the problem on Mac OS X.

Comment: I can also confirm this behaviour - unless specified explicitly in `build.properties` file, the sbt resolves to 0.13.8 version (even though 0.13.9 is installed). Using IDEA 14, I also tried to remove `.ivy` and `.sbt` directory after SBT 0.13.9 installation - to no avail.