# Upgraded to sbt 0.13.9; now I cannot launch sbt said to cannot get Scala 2.10.5

Tags: scala, sbt

Windows 7, if downloaded and installed sbt-0.13.9.msi, the issue is the same as [Why is sbt 0.13.9 reporting that it's 0.13.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051899/why-is-sbt-0-13-9-reporting-that-its-0-13-8) .

So I installed with sbt-0.13.9.zip,and removed the **.ivy2\cache** and **.sbt\boot** directory. But then sbt said to cannot get Scala 2.10.5:

```
C:\Users\s001>sbt 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 
Getting Scala  2.10.5 (for sbt)... 
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
            confs: [default]
            0 artifacts copied, 5 already retrieved (0kB/20ms) 
Error: Could not retrieve Scala 2.10.5: missing scala.Option, cala.tools.nsc.Global
```

But in the below scala-2.10.5\lib, there are:

```
jansi.jar jline.jar scala-compiler.jar scala-library.jar scala-reflect.jar

C:\USERS\S001\.SBT └─boot
    ├─other
    │  └─org.fusesource.jansi
    │      └─jansi
    │          └─1.11
    └─scala-2.10.5
        ├─lib
        └─org.scala-sbt
            └─sbt
                └─0.13.9
                    ├─compiler-interface-bin_2.10.5
                    ├─compiler-interface-bin_2.8.2.final
                    ├─compiler-interface-bin_2.9.2
                    ├─compiler-interface-bin_2.9.3
                    ├─compiler-interface-src
                    └─xsbti
```